# Why does call to jQuery's appendChild fail with undefined error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my simple HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="myParentDivElement">
        Hello World!
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is the accompanying JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myDOMElement = document.getElementById("myParentDivElement");

    var newDivID = "div_1";
    var newDiv = $('<div id="' + newDivID + '"/>');
    $( newDiv ).css('marginLeft', '50px');

    var newSpanID = "span_1";
    var newSpan = $('<span id="' + newSpanID + '"/>');
    newSpan.text('myLabel');
    newDiv.appendChild(newSpan);   
    $( myDOMElement ).appendChild(newDiv);
});
```

But when I run this code the line `newDiv.appendChild(newSpan);` gives the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Can someone explain why?
Here is the JSFiddle showing that it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/TsTMx/2/

Comment: Why not accept one of these answers?

Answer (score 18):

`.appendChild()` is a plain JavaScript method, not jQuery. The jQuery method is `.append()`.

```
newDiv.append(newSpan);   
$( myDOMElement ).append(newDiv);
```

Comment: `appendChild` is DOM, not JavaScript.

Comment: True that it is part of DOM but it is fair to say that it is a plain JavaScript method as opposed to a jQuery method.

Comment: DOM methods are provided by the browser and so tend to be written in C/C++/Objective-C, while jQuery is written in JS so, while `append` might end up calling the DOM method, it is written in JS itself :)

Answer (score 4):

Use [`.append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/)

```
newDiv.append(newSpan);
```

[.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) works with DOM element. `newDiv` is jQuery Object not a plain JavaScript DOM element.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/M7Hm3/)**

Answer (score 2):

`newDiv` is a jQuery object, not a DOM object.

jQuery objects do not have [an `appendChild` method](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#ID-184E7107), they have [an `append` method.](https://api.jquery.com/append/)